# c# .net framework 4.8 webapp binding redirect works on laptop, but not when deployed on IIS via build server (I have a netstandard dependency)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-standard

My framework 4.8 webapp sln (using package.config nuget), has a dependency on a netstandard2.0 lib. When I deploy the webapp, via build server, to IIS I get a binding redirect problem where the redirect in my web.config directs e.g.

```
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\xxx\yyy\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/af8f859d/2f94c10f/System.Buffers.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/af8f859d/2f94c10f/System.Buffers/System.Buffers.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/xxx/yyy/bin/System.Buffers.DLL.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\xxx\yyy\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.0.2.0 redirected to 4.0.3.0.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/af8f859d/2f94c10f/System.Buffers.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/af8f859d/2f94c10f/System.Buffers/System.Buffers.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/xxx/yyy/bin/System.Buffers.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

That redirect was generated by VS2019 (and works on my laptop) but it breaks on the IIS, because 4.0.3.0 isn't there, even though I've got "copy local" set.
I think my problem is something to do with netstandard (cc7b13ffcd2ddd51) having a different 4.0.2.0 version of that assembly that framework (b07...). If I tweak the redirect on the IIS, it works again, but that means my autogenerated binding redirects are no longer valid.

Any clues?

Comment: Are you testing it by using a local instance of IIS on your laptop separate from Visual Studio? Or, are you testing it by just running it directly from Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't deploy it on my laptop, I just hit F5.

Comment: That's why it works on your laptop. Visual Studio is not using the same settings as IIS or the build server for that matter. You could be using different msbuild version than your server, or you could be just IIS configs.

Comment: so, I have to manually tweak these bindings after I deploy? the copy local ought to have meant I'd get the correct assembly versions I'd expect in the bin folder?